# Dojo Custom Build Error

Tags: build, dojo

**My HTML File** : **buildCheck.html**

```
<SCRIPT src="/dojo/dojo.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
     dojo.require("my.app");

</SCRIPT>
```

**Command :**

```
>build.bat action=release htmlFiles=../../buildCheck1.html profile=myProfile
```

**Error :**

```
kwArgs.htmlFiles ../../buildCheck1.html
release:  Using profile: profiles/myProfile.profile.js
release:  Using version number: 0.0.0.dev for the release.
release:  Deleting: ../../release/dojo
release:  Copying: ../dojo/../dijit to: ../../release/dojo/dijit
release:   ********** Not Copied: ../dojo/../dijit
release:  Copying: ../dojo/../dojox to: ../../release/dojo/dojox
release:   ********** Not Copied: ../dojo/../dojox
release:  Copying: ../dojo to: ../../release/dojo/dojo
release:   ********** Not Copied: ../dojo
release:  Building dojo.js and layer files
js: "./../../dojo/_base/_loader/loader.js", line 423: exception from uncaught Ja
vaScript throw: Error: Could not load 'dojo.i18n'; last tried '../../release/doj
o/dojo/i18n.js'
```

I am geeting this error if i add the below component

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore")
```

after removal the component build is working fine.

What can be the issue?What should i add to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of myProfile?

Comment: @CraigSwing it is autogenerated from my buildCheck1.html file.If you still need it will post.

Comment: I have the same problem. The build script uses a wrong path of dojo when it wants to copy it in the release directory. This happens, if the html file includes a require of anything under dojo folder: `dojo.require("dojo.<*>")`. With `dojo.require("dijit.<*>")` or `dojo.require("dojox.<*>")` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at the point the error occurs, dojo/i18n has not yet been built. It seems weird to me, that you say it is the ItemFileReadStore - as noting in the dojo.data requires localization.

Try adding a manual dojo.require("dojo.i18n"); to your .html above any dijits reqs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you had your files organized, but in my case, I had it like this:

```
- js
  - dojo_require.js (the file with "dojo.require" statements, just like your "buildCheck.html")
  - dojo-release-1.6.1-src (dojo files)
    - dijit
    - dojo
    - dojox
    - util
      - buildscripts
    - release
```

And I faced exactly the same problem. I figured out this happens, when the html file contains any `require` that loads something from the 'dojo' folder. `dojo.require("dijit.<*>")` is fine, `dojo.require("dojox.<*>")` is fine, but `dojo.require("dojo.<*>")` causes the build script to use an incorrect relative path to dojo. I was getting the same output as you:

```
release:  Deleting: ../../release/dojo
release:  Copying: ../dojo/../dijit to: ../../release/dojo/dijit
```

But I should have got something like `Copying: ../../dojo/../dijit to: ../../release/dojo/dijit` instead. One `../` was missing.

Now, it is probably a bug (I am lazy to investigate it further), and since 1.6 is a pretty old version of dojo, the correct fix should be to upgrade. But since at some occasions, it is just too much pain, here is a dirty hack that made it possible for my buildscript to run and finish:

In `dojo-release-1.6.1-src/util/buildscripts/build.js`, on the line 107, add this line:

```
prefixPath = '../' + prefixPath;
```

So that the entire block of code looks like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
    var prefixName = prefixes[i][0];
    var prefixPath = prefixes[i][1];
    prefixPath = '../' + prefixPath; // HACK!
    var finalPrefixPath = prefixPath;
    if(finalPrefixPath.indexOf(".") == 0 && prefixName != "dojo"){
        finalPrefixPath = dojoPrefixPath + "/" + prefixPath;
    }
    _copyToRelease(prefixName, finalPrefixPath, kwArgs, buildLayers);

    if(kwArgs.symbol){
        var releasePath = kwArgs.releaseDir + "/"  + prefixName.replace(/\./g, "/");
        buildUtil.insertSymbols(releasePath, kwArgs);
    }
}
```